# Input to base64binary in Oracle

Tags: oracle, hash, plsql, base64

So I have this stored procedure in Microsof SQL Server that takes 2 parameters (password and salt) and produces a base64binary. i would like to transfer this logic in Oracle

`...
set @source = hashbytes('sha2_256',@password + @Salt)
set @encrypted=( select cast(N'' as xml).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:variable("@source"))', 'varchar(max)'))
...`

**SAMPLE DATA:**

@password=`1234567890123456` and @salt=`TESTTEST`

@source will be `0xC1DB209FD3B6873B0F35C2FB103CCC5E9C585C26F79048D575318AA70E17F07F`

and @encrypted will be `wdsgn9O2hzsPNcL7EDzMXpxYXCb3kEjVdTGKpw4X8H8=`

---

Trying to implement this i saw hash2 in oracle is a bit complicated so i thought ill try and at least do the base64binary part.

I tried this (and a few others) which i found in other questions here in SO

`function to_base64(t in varchar2) return varchar2 is
 begin
    return utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(utl_encode.base64_encode(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(t)));
end to_base64;`

but passing the @source value i get from the first step in MS SQL, I get different encoding string..

Is there something similar in Oracle? How should I do it?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a sample password and salt, and the expected result (whatever you'd get from SQL Server), and maybe the intermediate string that's being generated as source?

Comment: @AlexPoole added!

Comment: as far as I can read "microsoft SQL server" commands, they do not produce base64binary format for password and salt, but they produce "sha2_256" encrypted string. This is not the same as using utl_encode.base64_encode

Comment: @OracleDev yes, maybe am understanding the code wrong.. am a newbie in both! but basically i want the result MS sql gives with oracle :) i guess ill change the title accordingly!

Comment: @OracleDev also to clarify, in the oracle `to_base64()` am passing the @'source result i get from MS sql

Comment: Also what result did you get with your code - `QzFEQjIw...NzUzMThBQTcwRTE3RjA3Rg==`maybe? Or `MHhDMUR...MTdGMDdG`?

Comment: @AlexPoole i was getting the second one `MHhDMUR...MTdGMDdG`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `dbms_crypto.hash()` to hash the password+salt value; you need to convert that to `raw` first, and the result is also `raw`.

Then convert that `raw` hashed value to base64, which is still `raw`; and then finally convert that to `varchar2`.

```
declare
  l_password varchar2(30) := '1234567890123456';
  l_salt varchar2(30) := 'TESTTEST';
  l_raw raw(256);
  l_hash raw(256);
  l_base64_raw raw(256);
  l_base64 varchar2(256);
begin
  l_raw := utl_i18n.string_to_raw(data => l_password || l_salt, dst_charset => 'AL32UTF8');
  l_hash := dbms_crypto.hash(src => l_raw, typ => dbms_crypto.hash_sh256);
  dbms_output.put_line(l_hash);
  l_base64_raw := utl_encode.base64_encode(l_hash);
  dbms_output.put_line(l_base64_raw);
  l_base64 := utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(l_base64_raw);
  dbms_output.put_line(l_base64);
end;
/

C1DB209FD3B6873B0F35C2FB103CCC5E9C585C26F79048D575318AA70E17F07F
776473676E394F32687A73504E634C3745447A4D58707859584362336B456A566454474B707734583848383D
wdsgn9O2hzsPNcL7EDzMXpxYXCb3kEjVdTGKpw4X8H8=


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Or as a function, simplified slightly:

```
create or replace function hash_base64 (p_password varchar2, p_salt varchar2)
return varchar2
is
  l_raw raw(256);
  l_hash raw(256);
  l_base64 varchar2(256);
begin
  l_raw := utl_i18n.string_to_raw(data => p_password || p_salt, dst_charset => 'AL32UTF8');
  l_hash := dbms_crypto.hash(src => l_raw, typ => dbms_crypto.hash_sh256);
  l_base64 := utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(r => utl_encode.base64_encode(l_hash));
  return l_base64;
end;
/    

select hash_base64 ('1234567890123456', 'TESTTEST') from dual;

HASH_BASE64('1234567890123456','TESTTEST')        
--------------------------------------------------
wdsgn9O2hzsPNcL7EDzMXpxYXCb3kEjVdTGKpw4X8H8=
```

---

I think the problem with what you were doing was that you were passing in the `source` value as a string, and then casting that string to `raw`; i.e. you were passing the string value `'C1DB2...'` and casting that to `raw`, rather than passing that `raw` value.

So you'd effectively do something like:

```
declare
  l_base64 varchar2(256);
begin
  l_base64 := utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(
                utl_encode.base64_encode(
                  utl_raw.cast_to_raw('C1DB209FD3B6873B0F35C2FB103CCC5E9C585C26F79048D575318AA70E17F07F')));
  dbms_output.put_line(l_base64);
end;
/
```

which gets

```
QzFEQjIwOUZEM0I2ODczQjBGMzVDMkZCMTAzQ0NDNUU5QzU4NUMyNkY3OTA0OEQ1NzUzMThBQTcwRTE3RjA3Rg==
```

or maybe you included the `0x` prefix, which gets:

```
MHhDMURCMjA5RkQzQjY4NzNCMEYzNUMyRkIxMDNDQ0M1RTlDNTg1QzI2Rjc5MDQ4RDU3NTMxOEFBNzBFMTdGMDdG
```

Rather than casting that string to `raw`, you can just pass it as a `raw` literal:

```
declare
  l_base64 varchar2(256);
begin
  l_base64 := utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(
                utl_encode.base64_encode('C1DB209FD3B6873B0F35C2FB103CCC5E9C585C26F79048D575318AA70E17F07F'));
  dbms_output.put_line(l_base64);
end;
/

wdsgn9O2hzsPNcL7EDzMXpxYXCb3kEjVdTGKpw4X8H8=
```

Comment: You are the man dude! Thank you very much! Not only you gave me some code, you also explained and pointed my mistakes :D i really appreciate your time